# GPU rendering for video

Tags: rendering, video, gpu

I use Blender since many years to video editing. I don't use 3D items in my videos, just 2-3 video strip. But the video rendering is slow because Blender don't use GPU for this job. But I just want to know if, with the new version 3.0, it's possible to use GPU for this. Can you help me ?

I use a NVidia GeForce GTX 960 on Linux Mint.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to hook up with that question. As long as my knowledge goes, all video rendering is done via CPU, only the actual video output to a viewport and 3D scene rendering may be done by GPU. If there were a possibility to outsource the video rendering to the GPU, i would greatly appreciate to use it.

In the options, the only place were GPU/CPU usage may be configured is at "Edit/Preferences/System/Cycles Render Device".

My video card (GeForce RTX 2060) is able to on-the-fly render captured video on two channels (to twitch as well as youtube) alongside rendering a game, while the CPU is rendering the last edited video in the background. The GPU load by that twitch/youtube rendering is minimal (barely visible in the process explorer). Thus i would expect that the performance of video rendering, if blender could outsource it to the GPU, would be better by at least a factor of 10.

With the upgrade from Blender 2.9 to Blender 3.0, the video render performance per single video has been enhanced: It now uses all available CPU power. In Blender up to 2.9, only a part of around 1/3 of the available CPU power was used. Thus until today, i handled that by letting two to three videos render in the background simultaneously. But the render performance over all instances combined is still the same in Blender 3.0.

Comment: Clarification - your graphics card has a hardware encoder.  It's not rendering two video files, it's taking the rendered frames from your game play and *encoding* them to h.264 video stream with a dedicated copper circuit that is designed to do exactly that and nothing else, that's why the load is so minimal

Comment: @Allen Simpson: Yes, exactly. And it would be a great thing if blender would use the graphics hardware support for its own video rendering.